# Illegal Instruction 4 in C

Tags: c, strtol

I am writing a program to print out the atomic weight of the formula inputted. Everything works until I pass in "H2O2" or letter-number-letter-number. It displays the error illegal instruction and can't seem to find why it's not working. It reads the individual elements from a file to determine the atomic weight and symbol name.

```
void separate(){
    char compound[1024];
    char displayFormula[1024];
    int cIndex = 0;
    char nameBUF[25];
    char *remaining;
    int numBUF = 0;
    float weight = 0;
    int find;
    int clear;
    int clear2;
    int clear3;

    printf("Chemical composition? ");

    while(fgets(compound, 100, stdin) != NULL){/*takes in the formula from input and loops until EOF is detected*/

        compound[strlen(compound)-1] = '\0';/*null terminator to end of array*/

        strcpy(displayFormula, compound);/*copy contents from compound to another array for later printing*/

        while(compound[cIndex] != '\0'){/*loops while null terminator is not encountered*/
            if(isupper(compound[cIndex])){
                if(islower(compound[cIndex+1])){/*if the next character after the upper letter is lowercase copy the two letters to temporary buffer*/
                    strncpy(nameBUF, compound+cIndex, 2);
                    nameBUF[2] = '\0';
                    cIndex += 2;
                }
                else{
                    strncpy(nameBUF, compound+cIndex, 1);/*anything else copy only the first letter to the temporary buffer*/
                    nameBUF[1] = '\0';
                    cIndex += 1;
                }
            }

            if(compound[cIndex] == '\0'){/*else if it is the null terminator, the number is 1*/
                numBUF = 1;
            }
            else if(isalpha(compound[cIndex])){/*if character at next index is a letter, the number is 1*/

                numBUF = 1;
            }
            else{
                numBUF = strtol(compound+cIndex, &remaining, 10);/*if it is a number, store it to temporary buffer and overwrite the char array with the remaining characters*/
                strcpy(compound,remaining);
                cIndex++;
            }

            for(find = 0; find < 118; find++){
                if(strcmp(arr[find].symbol, nameBUF) == 0){
                    weight += (numBUF)*(arr[find].atomicweight);/*if matched with the symbol, add atomic weight*/
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(weight == 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: no such element\n", nameBUF);/*error messages if symbol is not in the list*/
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: not a valid compound\n", displayFormula);
                break;
            }

            numBUF = 0;

            for(clear = 0; clear < strlen(nameBUF);clear++){
                nameBUF[clear] = '\0';/*clear char array buffer*/
            }
        }

        if(weight != 0){
            printf("The atomic weight of %s is %.02f\n", displayFormula, weight);/*print atomic weight*/
        }
        else if(weight == 0){/*resets variables if weight is 0*/
            numBUF = 0;

            for(clear = 0; clear < strlen(nameBUF);clear++){
                nameBUF[clear] = '\0';
            }
        }
        printf("Chemical composition? ");
        weight = 0;/*resets variables*/
        cIndex = 0;
        for(clear2 = 0; clear2 < strlen(compound); clear2++){/*clears arrays*/
            compound[clear2] = '\0';
        }
        for(clear3 = 0; clear3 < strlen(displayFormula); clear3++){
            displayFormula[clear3] = '\0';
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This won't be the cause of Illegal Instruction, but routines like `for(clear = 0; clear < strlen(nameBUF);clear++) nameBUF[clear] = '\0';` will clear only the first element of the arrays because after overwriting the first element, `strlen(nameBUF)` will be zero.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! Just wondering, why won't strcpy work for memory overlap?

Comment: Re. Why `strcpy` doesn’t support overlap, the simple answer is: because it has been defined that way in the standard (also, current versions qualify the arguments with `restrict`, which means essentially the same). As for why that is, basically it’s a lot harder to write an efficient copy with support for overlap - I suggest an exercise: write your own `strcpy` first without overlap support, then try to figure out what goes wrong when the strings overlap and think about ways to support overlap. If you figure it out, compare the complexity and/or performance of the overlap vs no overlap…